# T-SQL query with date range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a fairly weird 'bug' with a simple query, and I vaguely remember reading the reason for it somewhere a long time ago but would love someone to refresh my memory.

The table is a basic ID, Datetime table.

The query is:

```
select ID, Datetime from Table where Datetime <= '2010-03-31 23:59:59'
```

The problem is that the query results include results where the Datetime is '2010-04-01 00:00:00'.  The next day.  Which it shouldn't.

Anyone?

Cheers

Moo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [How Are Dates Stored In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-are-dates-stored-in-sql-server) and [How Does Between Work With Dates In SQL Server?](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/how-does-between-work-with-dates-in-sql-)

If that is a smalldatetime it has 1 minute precision so if rounds up, for datetime it is 300 miliseconds

example

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SELECT @d = '2001-12-31 23:59:59.999'

SELECT @d
```

2002-01-01 00:00:00.000

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME
SELECT @d = '2001-12-31 23:59:59.998'

SELECT @d
```

2001-12-31 23:59:59.997

Always use less than next day at midnight, in your case

```
< '20100401'
```

Comment: +1 for explaining what's really going on, and not just listing one of the work-arounds.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, it fits what I remember - however, I just realised something about my experience the other day which doesn't quite fit into either of your examples.  In my case, 2010-04-01 was being included for time values of 23:59:59 right down to 23:59:30.  23:59:29 excluded the errant day from the result set.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

try doing it like:

```
select ID, Datetime from Table where Datetime < '2010-04-01'
```

I always floor the datetime and increment the day and just use "<" less than.

to floor a datetime to just the day use:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,  GETDATE()   ),0)
```

you can easily increment a datetime by using addition:

```
SELECT GETDATE()+1
```

by using the '23:59:59' you can miss rows, try it out:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (RowID int, DateOf datetime)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (1,'2010-03-31 10:00')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (2,'2010-03-31')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (3,'2010-03-31 23:59:59')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (4,'2010-03-31 23:59:59.887')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (5,'2010-04-01')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (6,'2010-04-01 10:00')
select * from @YourTable where DateOf <= '2010-03-31 23:59:59'
```

OUTPUT

```
RowID       DateOf
----------- -----------------------
1           2010-03-31 10:00:00.000
2           2010-03-31 00:00:00.000
3           2010-03-31 23:59:59.000

(3 row(s) affected
```

this query is wrong, because it does not find the missed rowID=4 record.

if you try to fix this with:

```
select * from @YourTable where DateOf <= '2010-03-31 23:59:59.999'
```

then RowID=5 will be included as well, which is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It's very odd that you are seeing that; I don't know why. But I will suggest that you write the query this way instead:

```
select ID, Datetime from Table where Datetime < '2010-04-01'
```