# DataTimePicker for ListView

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ado.net

Is there a way to use **DateTimePicker** as your searching device for **ListView?**

I don't know how to use DateTimePicker as my search engine...

HERE IS THE CODES FOR MY SEARCH:

```
Dim conn As SqlConnection
Dim cmd As SqlCommand
Dim da As SqlDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim itemcoll(100) As String

Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
Me.ListView1.GridLines = True
ListView1.Items.Clear()

conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=#####;Initial Catalog=#####;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=#####;Password=#####")
Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
strQ = "SELECT ControlNo,EmpNo,CheckOutDate,CheckOutTime,TaxiNo,PlateNo,Model,Make FROM dbo.ChkInOut WHERE ControlNo ='" + txtsearch.Text + "'"

cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
ds = New DataSet
da.Fill(ds, "Table")
Dim i As Integer = 0
Dim j As Integer = 0
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
    For j = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
        itemcoll(j) = ds.Tables(0).Rows(i)(j).ToString()
    Next
    Dim lvi As New ListViewItem(itemcoll)
    Me.ListView1.Items.Add(lvi)
 Next
```

Comment: I just want to EXECUTE SELECT STATEMENT in DateTimePicker wherein when I selected a specific day/date . the ListView will populate itself the data from my DB in SQL SERVER where the transaction was made at the same date the user picks on DateTimePicker

Comment: sir R0MANARMY ive been doing this one program lately, all my questions was about it. like how to populate listview, how to connect to db using SQLconnection, etc. etc. I will post my search statement here, could you tell me where to put it?

Comment: You should try to format your code better before you post it.  Also, this is a much better question (more specific).  I'm going to delete my previous comments because they are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are  few problems with your code as is, so let's take them one at a time

1. [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) inherits from [`DbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbcommand.aspx), which implements the [`IDisposable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IDisposable.aspx) interface.

   > The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.

   The best way do that is with the [`Using`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887831/how-does-the-using-statement-translate-from-c-sharp-to-vb) keyword.  For a code example of that, take a look at the sample code at the bottom of [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) page.

   Same goes for [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx), wrap it in a `Using` statement.
2. Don't concatenate strings together to make SQL queries, this opens your application up to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.  There are examples of how to create parameterized queries [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210927192856/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092601-1.2.shtml) *(unfortunately I didn't see a good example on MSDN)*.

   In your case, the query will look like this:

   ```
   strQ = "SELECT ControlNo, ..<rest of columns>.. ,Model,Make " & _
          "FROM dbo.ChkInOut " & _
          "WHERE ControlNo = @controlNo"

   cmd = New SqlCommand(strQ, conn)
   cmd.Parameters.AddWidthValue("@controlNo", txtsearch.Text);

         ... rest of code here ...
   ```
3. To query by a user specified date, you need to first get the date from the [DateTimePicker.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.value.aspx) property.  Then construct a query (like in the example above) and pass a parameter with the selected date.  You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865834/t-sql-query-with-date-range) abou SQL Server dates helpful.

Comment: cmd.Parameters.Add("@controlNo", txtsearch.Text);

this line of codes has a problem it says 'Public Function Add(parameterName As String, value As Object) As System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter' is obselete: 'Add (String parameterName, Object value ) has been deprecated.' Use AddWidthValue(String parametername, Object value)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the `Add` method is now obsolete.  I've updated the answer.  However, the error message even tells you what the problem is **and** how to fix it.  The `Add` is obsolete, use `AddWithValue` instead.

Comment: sorry im newbie in programming field. sorry

Comment: Don't be sorry, just read error messages, google things you don't understand, and if you still don't find an answer, then ask someone.

Comment: one question, why not stay with the codes that I made? what is the advantages of the codes that you post sir R0MANARMY? BTW, I used your codes and it works fine.

Comment: same, but I've read the link about SQL Injections and all I think is that it's for me to have a clear and short codes instead of using long codes like what I always do... am I right about it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23825/discussion-between-r0manarmy-and-danjor)